# Trying to get property 'firstname' of non-object Laravel 5.7

Tags: laravel-5.7

I have a question why I'm getting undefined variable in my blade view "Trying to get property 'firstname' of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\focus\resources\views\assets\asset.blade.php)"

asset.blade.php

```
    <tbody>
                        @foreach($assets as $asset)
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{ $asset->employee->firstname }} {{ $asset->$employee->lastname }}</td>
<!--this where the error came-->
                                <td>{{ $asset->employee->account->name }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $asset->employee->position }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $asset->workstation }}</td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td>{{ $asset->remarks }}</td>
                                <td>


                                </td>
                            </tr>
                    @endforeach
                    </tbody>
```

Asset.php

```
public function employee()
{
   return $this->belongsTo('App\Employee');
}
```

Employee.php

```
public function asset()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Asset');
}
```

I haven't really no idea where this error came from

output of dd($assets)

[image: output of dd($assets)]

Answer (score 0):

Try `$asset->employee->x` instead of `$asset->$employee->x`.

Notice the `$`.

When you write `$asset->$employee` it assumes `$employee` exists, which does not, hence the error.

Comment: I edit the question sir and I change it to $asset->employee->x and what happens is trying to get property of non-object

Comment: Can you edit the question and add the output of `dd($assets);` in your controller. It looks like you have assets without a relation to employee? Or perhaps an employee object without an account.

Comment: I declare the relationships in my models

Comment: That does not mean the data exists in your template. If an asset exists in de database, but no employee is attached to it, then you will never be able to display `$asset->employee->account->name`. You will get a `"Trying to get property 'x' of non-object` error. In your case the asset you fetch from the database has a relation defined in the model, but it does not exist in your database. `$asset->employee` is not an Employee object, but `null`. So you get the error that you are trying to get the property `firstname` of a non-object.

Comment: But I have a foreign key in my asset table which emp_id

Comment: Please add the output of `dd($assets);` to your question as I requested in my second comment.

Comment: I updated the question with the results of dd($assets)